# How to display single textView multiple time in android?

Tags: android, textview

I'm working on a chat App where I want to display message in a textView but when I send the message it display in same textView as list. So how can I display the messages multiple time using one textView or two?

Comment: use RecyclerView https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a listView or a RecyclerView to show the message thread, with that whenever a new message will be added to the list a new line will be created.

Comment: But I don't want to use any listView or RecyclerView. As it possible without this??

Comment: then you need to add the textView dynamically everytime you receive a message.

Comment: wheres the problem coming?

Comment: listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatlist);

        String[] chat = {"Parent", "Tea"};
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, chat);
        ListView list_Item = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatlist);
        list_Item.setAdapter(listAdapter);

Comment: when the string chat have two values it show the textView two time not as required